# Transfer music to ipod

Tags: banshee, ipod, amarok

I've been trying to add music to my ipod nano from ubuntu with no luck. I've tried Amarok, kgtpod and Banshee all with the same result:

I can add music to the ipod in the program, and it seems to work (in Amarok and Banshee I can play the new music from the ipod within the program).

But when I close the program and unmount the ipod (alternatively unmount/disconnect the ipod from within the program) the new music is not on it. If I reconnect the ipod to the computer and start one of the programs the new music has disappeared from the ipod.

In an answer to another question there was something about initializing the ipod on windows first, but I assume that's not necessary since it shows up in the programs?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with rythmbox. I use rythmbox to transfer music to my 3rd generation iPod nano. With rythmbox all you have to do is drag the music to your iPods icon and it will transfer the music. You can check if it has transferred if your iPod shows that it is syncing.

Comment: The exact same thing happens when I try using Rhythmbox even though it indicated it was syncing and then that the new music was on it (the other programs also did this).

Comment: Which generation iPod is it? I know that the newer iOS devices have trouble syncing on Ubuntu but I did not think the same would be true for the iPod nano

Comment: Not sure, the box says ipod nano 8GB silver and Model A1366

Comment: Its the 6th generation iPod. You could try using it on windows as you said in the question. I do not really know if that's problem but I set up my iPod on windows long before using it on linux

Comment: Tried this out. It still works. Just make sure to first move the songs into your play queue and then move it to the ipod. If you try to directly move the songs from your folder to the ipod by drag and drop, it will not work